# stopPropagation() without changing children

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, { passive: false });

function touchHandler(e) {
  if (e.type == "touchstart") {
    alert("You touched the screen!");
  } else if (e.type == "touchmove") {
    alert("You moved your finger!");
  } else if (e.type == "touchend" || e.type == "touchcancel") {
    alert("You removed your finger from the screen!");
  }
}

<div id="parent">
 <div id="mid">
  <div id="children" />
 </div>
</div>
```

My question might be impractical and make not sense, but I wonder if it's possible. Assume the parent has a touch eventlistener and we **cannot** modify the children

Is it possible to prevent the event bubbling up to trig the parent listener via `<div id="mid">` when we touch the children.

I do have a idea to detect if I'm touching the children and cancelling the function, but can we prevent bubbling up from `mid`?

Comment: Don't use `alert`, use console logging with remote debugging. alert _halts the browser process and nothing will run_ until it's dismissed. It is horrendously legacy.

Comment: Yes, that's why you got a comment, not an answer: don't use alert, not even in example code. Getting nitpicked by people knowledgeable in a subject field is one of the things you can expect when asking those people for help. If you use obsolete programming patterns, you're going to get comments telling you to stop using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the `touchHandler` function, check the target of the event. If it's on one of the children, don't continue.

```
function touchHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('#children')) return;
```

Comment: that's my idea right now, my question is will it cause any performance problem since we are the touching event keep firing and we keep searching the element, thanks

Comment: Performance impact will be next to nothing. Modern hardware can handle quite a lot of things.

Comment: @Yunhai That's not the question you asked

Comment: @Dexygen if you said so, then you can remind me I need to re-define my question, :\. Anyway, thanks